# Trying to combine two kinds of NGINX Location Directives

Tags: nginx

Good day. I have been tasked with writing a Location Directive for files in a folder `/themes/` matching `jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc`

I have two mutually exclusive directives:

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
    ...
}
```

and

```
location /images/ {
     ...
}
```

I have read if or else qualifiers are strongly discouraged in location directives for NGINX.

I tried studying several articles on NGINX Location headers and tested multiple versions. None worked.

Answer (score 0):

So you want a location directive that only matches specific file types inside the subdirectory `/images`? So you want to serve `/images/test.jpg` but not `/test.jpg`? Do you want to match `/images/xxx/test.jpg`?

Your first location block defines a regular expression, you can just put the condition for the `/images` at the start in there, like the following:

```
location ~* ^\/images\/.*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ { ... ... }
```

https://regex101.com/r/Elk2RM/1